# Is it possible to join two tables on a column that contains a mix of castable and uncastable data?

Tags: sql, join, implicit-conversion

Apologies if this has been asked before, I combed through a lot of questions but wasn't able to find an answer I could apply to this problem.

I'm putting together an SSRS report from a database I have read-only access to and am having trouble selecting the data in the format I would like.

```
Table 1: Referenced Data
==== ============= 
 ID   Description  
==== ============= 
 1    Apple        
 2    Orange       
 3    Pear         
==== ============= 

Table 2: Records
==== ====== ======== 
 ID   Data    Tag   
==== ====== ======== 
 1   1      List    
 2   2      List    
 3   Red    String  
 4   Blue   String  
 5   3      List    
==== ====== ========
```

What I would like to see is:

```
Report
========== ========= 
 RecordNo   Content  
========== ========= 
    1       Apple    
    2       Orange   
    3       Red      
    4       Blue     
    5       Pear     
========== =========
```

The problem is the Data column of T2 is nvarchar while the ID column of T1 is bigint. While I can avoid a conversion error by selecting only rows with the List tag, I lose the String data.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do in a select statement? It feels like this is something that could be done with some creativity, but I'm still in the learning process and my SQL isn't quite there yet.

Comment: Which dbms????????

Comment: Hi Eric, apologies it was SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    rec.Id
    ,Content = CASE WHEN data.Id IS NOT NULL THEN data.Description ELSE rec.Data END
FROM
    Records rec
    LEFT JOIN ReferencedData data
    ON rec.Tag <> 'String'
    AND rec.Data = CAST(data.Id AS NVARCHAR(50))
```

You can cast the `BIGINT` to `NVARCHAR` as part of your join condition which will avoid the implicit conversion error.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, Matt. This did the trick. I was so busy racking my brains over the string to bigint conversion error I never even considered casting the bigint instead. And thanks to everyone that took the time to help out with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
;WITH DataNum AS
(
 SELECT ID, Data FROM Records WHERE ISNUMERIC(Data) = 1
)
SELECT dn.ID, rd.Description
FROM DataNum dn
JOIN ReferencedData rd ON dn.Data = rd.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, Data
FROM Records
WHERE ISNUMERIC(Data) <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select table2.id
     , coalesce(table1.description, table2.Data) content
  from table2
  left join table1
    on table2.tag <> 'String'
   and table1.id = table2.data
 order by table2.id
```

This works in MySQL ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d24e2b/8)) but requires a slight change in SQL Server ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f9e25/3)) and Oracle ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/186e5b/4)):

```
select table2.id
     , coalesce(table1.description,table2.Data) content
  from table2
  left join table1
    on table2.tag <> 'String'
   and table1.id = case when table2.tag <> 'String' then table2.data end
 order by table2.id
```

and PostgreSQL ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1ab7f/9)) needs a further tweek:

```
select table2.id
    , coalesce(table1.description,table2.Data) as content
  from table2
  left join table1
    on table2.tag <> 'String'
   and cast(table1.id as varchar(6)) = table2.data
 order by table2.id
```